# ORC is file is not giving records in same order in which they were written

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I have recently started using ORC file to keep some records on disk. I write the records in ORC file in batches using save mode append.

But when reading the records from the same ORC file, I am getting the records in a different order.

Following is a small sample of code which I am using.

To write records -

```
private void serializeRowList(List<Object[]> rowsToCache, int chunkNumber) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            String orcCompatibleLocalPath = "some_path";    
            sqlContext.createDataFrame(ScalaUtils.convertObjectArrayListToRddOfRows(rowsToCache), schema).write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").save(orcCompatibleLocalPath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

The Rows which I am saving to ORC file are coming in chunks and they will be appended in same file.

Now I am reading the same file in following way:-

```
RDD<Row> rows = sqlContext.read().format("orc").load(orcCompatibleLocalPath).rdd();
```

Now I am getting more than one partitions in the RDD even though I haven't applied any partitioning and saved ORC file size is way less than hdfs default block size.

Also when getting the local iterator from using following code -

```
rowIterator = rdd.toLocalIterator();
```

I am getting records in different order than the order in which they were saved.

I need help to identify what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior:

- In general case Spark doesn't guarantee specific order.
- `Append` mode doesn't append to file, it appends to directory.
- Spark SQL data soruces no longer depend on Hadoop configuration to determine input splits.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can make sure that records are in same order in which they were written.